# Retrfoit : send jsonObject as @RequestBody with @Multipart

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, okhttp

I want send json object to server with Retrofit as RequestBody

```
 {"attach": {
    "image": {
        "height": 1473,
        "urlRef": "",
        "width": 1473
    },
    "video": {
        "duration": "4.365",
        "height": 1920,
        "thumbUrl": "",
        "urlRef": "",
        "width": 1080
    }
}
}
```

and this my retrofit object

```
  Retrofit.Builder retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJavaCallAdapterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());
```

this is my retrofit interface :

```
@Multipart
@POST("post/")
Observable<Response> postAttach(
        @Part("attach") RequestBody asset
        , @Part MultipartBody.Part attachment
);
```

and create RequestBody as below:

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"), gson.toJson(myAttach));
```

but this request send json as string not json object

So how I can send as jsonObejct?

note: if I use @Body send as json object
but in I can not use @Body with @MultiPart!

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late to answer this question. I hope it'll be useful to post an answer here.

As you said in your question,

> but this request send json as string not json object

That `RequestBody#create()` accepts following (possible) parameters.

1. `create(@Nullable MediaType contentType, String content)`
2. `create(@Nullable MediaType contentType, ByteString content)`
3. `create(@Nullable MediaType contentType, byte[] content)`
4. `create(@Nullable MediaType contentType, byte[] content,
     int offset, int byteCount)`
5. `create(@Nullable MediaType contentType, File file)`

As you can see there's no argument type which accepts JSONObject. You need to pass JSON in `String` format.

Still you can post JSON body with Multipart upload.

You need to do the following changes.

In interface

```
@Multipart
@POST("post/")
Observable<Response> postAttach(
    @Part RequestBody asset,           // <==== just remove ("attach")
    @Part MultipartBody.Part attachment
);
```

Create the following POJO classes.

Image class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Image {

   @SerializedName("height")
   @Expose
   private int height;
   @SerializedName("urlRef")
   @Expose
   private String urlRef;
   @SerializedName("width")
   @Expose
   private int width;

   public Image(int height, String urlRef, int width) {
      this.height = height;
      this.urlRef = urlRef;
      this.width = width;
   }

   // other constructors, getter and setter methods
}
```

Video class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Video {

   @SerializedName("duration")
   @Expose
   private String duration;
   @SerializedName("height")
   @Expose
   private int height;
   @SerializedName("thumbUrl")
   @Expose
   private String thumbUrl;
   @SerializedName("urlRef")
   @Expose
   private String urlRef;
   @SerializedName("width")
   @Expose
   private int width;

   public Video(String duration, int height, String thumbUrl, String urlRef, int width) {
      this.duration = duration;
      this.height = height;
      this.thumbUrl = thumbUrl;
      this.urlRef = urlRef;
      this.width = width;
   }

   // other constructors, getter and setter methods
}
```

Attach class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Attach {

   @SerializedName("image")
   @Expose
   private Image image;
   @SerializedName("video")
   @Expose
   private Video video;

   public Attach(Image image, Video video) {
      this.image = image;
      this.video = video;
   }

   // constructors, getter and setter methods
}
```

MyAttach class

```
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class MyAttach {

   @SerializedName("attach")
   @Expose
   private Attach attach;

   public MyAttach(Attach attach) {
      this.attach = attach;
   }

   // other constructors, getter and setter methods    
}
```

Usage of the above classes in code.

```
Image image = new Image(1473, "image_url", 1473);
Video video = new Video(4.365, 1920, "thumb_url", "video_url", 1080);
Attach attach = new Attach(image, video);
MyAttach attach = new MyAttach(attach);

// finally serialize the above MyAttach object into JSONObject
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(attach);
```

And pass this JSON data into interface.

```
RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(
                         MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), // notice I'm using "multipart/form-data"
                         json
                         );
```

Pass it to interface

```
MultipartBody.Part attachment = // prepare file to upload
// other codes here
YourCustomResponseClassHere call = yourService.postAttach(requestBody, attachment);
call.enqueue({ /* your implementation */ });
```

Comment: what if instead of image_url we have to actually send any image from storage then this format won't work... Can you update your answer?